# Is there a cryptographic solution to provide a “proof of exclusion”?

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs

I would like a proof that accomplishes the following:

$N$ strings are part of a set $S$.  There is a `do_proof` function on set $S$ that produces a **succinct** witness statement $P$.

$$P = \text{do_proof}(S)$$

For some new string $X$ that is not part of set $S$, I have some proof

$$\text{prove_not_a_member}(X, P) = \text{True}$$

that proves that $X$ is not a member of $S$. Assume that $S$ is large and $P$ is constrained in size.

I was thinking about aggregate signatures but I'm not sure. Basically I am looking for a way to succinctly prove non-membership.  It does not have to be zero-knowledge.

Is there a cryptographic solution to provide a “proof of exclusion”?

Comment: Could you please [**edit your question**](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/53991/edit) and add some details related to the exact scenario? Currently I am not really clear about the reason for not being able to use a “proof of membership”. – In that case a result `is_a_member = false` boils down to an alike “isn’t a member’ result and it would surely simplify many aspects of your problem. Things like group signatures and ring signatures come to mind, somewhat as described in the [Proving membership of a group without revealing identity?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26612/12164) Q&A

Comment: On the other side, there’s the [Proof of non-membership on a Merkle tree?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31914/proof-of-non-membership-on-a-merkle-tree) Q&A which *could* render your question a duplicate.

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "succint"? Constant size? Sub-linear in $|S|$? And can you tolerate some risk of failures (i.e. some $X \notin S$ such that the non-membership proof fails)? It seems to me that if you want a sub-linear proof, can't tolerate a non-negligible failure rate, and if $S$ has no special structure, then you're going to bump against [Shannon's source coding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem) which basically says that there's no way to losslessly compress arbitrary random data.

Answer (score 2):

As shown recently$^1$ in [BBF], this can be carried out using *universal accumulators* [BdM].

Their construction is in the discrete-log setting in groups of unknown order (e.g., [RSA group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) or [class groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group)) and the size of both proofs of membership and non-membership is independent of the size of the set committed to. The security proof is in the [generic group model](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-48285-7_24.pdf) under an "adaptive root" assumption. The main components of their construction is a hash function $H$ that maps strings to primes and a proof of exponentiation [W]. A long overview can be found in [this](https://www.gakonst.com/deep-dive-rsa-accumulators) blog-post. A shorter overview is given below.

*Overview of the construction*. Let's fix a group $G$ of prime order $p$ with a generator $g$. Loosely speaking, the value of the accumulator for a set $S$ is
$$\pi:=g^{\Pi_{s\in S}H(s)}.$$
To prove membership of an element $s^*$ in $S$, the prover gives out the co-factor, i.e., the product of all elements in $S$ except $s^*$:
$$\pi^*:=g^{\Pi_{s\in S\setminus\{s^*\}}H(s)}.$$
Given $\pi$ and $\pi^*$, the verifier simply checks whether $\pi=(\pi^*)^{H(s)}$.

Proving non-membership of an element $s^*$ in $S$ is trickier and requires an application of [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) that is due to Shamir [S]. Since $H$ maps elements to primes, with high probability $h^*=H(s^*)$ and $h=\Pi_{s\in S}H(s)$ will be co-prime and therefore there exists two numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $ah^*+bh=1$. The proof now is $\pi^*:=(g^a,b)$ and the verifier checks whether
$$(g^a)^{h^*}\cdot\pi^b=g.$$

$^1$ The ideas were probably known before, but I couldn't find an earlier reference.

[BBF]: Boneh, Bünz and Fisch, *[Batching Techniques for Accumulators with Applications to IOPs and Stateless Blockchains](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1188)*, Crypto 19

[BdM]: Benaloh and de Mare, [One-way Accumulators: A Decentralized Alternative to Digital  Signatures](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-48285-7_24.pdf), Eurocrypt 93

[S]: Shamir, [On the generation of cryptographically strong pseudorandom sequences.](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-10843-2_43.pdf), TOCS 83

[W]: Wesolowski, [Efficient verifiable delay functions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/623), Eurocrypt 19