# How to Update Non-Membership Witness upon deletion in RSA Dynamic Universal Accumulator

Tags: rsa, accumulators

The [Universal Accumulator paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-540-72738-5_17.pdf) mentions the following for updating **non-membership witness** upon **member deletion**.

> Choose $r$ such that $a\hat x − rx ∈ Z$<sub>$2^l$</sub>

What is Z<sub>$2^l$</sub> and how can we efficiently evaluate $r$?

I suppose we need to brute force search by guessing values of r, is there any room for optimization here? Perhaps by making an educated guess about the value of r.

***Update:***

Can it be that $a\hat x − rx$ can be construed as $a\hat x$ $mod x$? If yes, then we can find

$\hat a = a\hat x$ $modx$

And,

$r = (a\hat x - \hat a)/x$

Am I right in assuming this?

Comment: Does [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81054/update-non-member-witness-in-rsa-accumulator/81638#81638) answer help?

Comment: thanks for your response @Occams_Trimmer, I looked at it before but that answer mentions about Update during addition only. I was able to follow that successfully but the update on deletion seems trickier.

Answer (score 1):

The updated Non-Membership Witness ($\hat a, \hat d$) upon deleting a member $\hat x$ can be calculated as follows:

$\hat a = a\hat x\mod x$

$r = (a\hat x - \hat a)/x$

$ \hat d = (d\hat c$ <sup>-r</sup> )$\mod n$

Hope this is useful to future developers trying to deconstruct these equations.